# google chrome pdf extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Am trying to make a google chrome  extension that will handle pdf downloads. I want it to save the dowloadeed pdfs on a particular folder or send them to server. Am stuck please help. This is what I have done.
My manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "PDF",
    "version": "1.0.1",
    "description": "test extension second trial",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "author": "Petach",
    "action": {
        "default_popup":"popup.html"
    },
    "icons": {
        "16":"icons/16.png",
        "32":"icons/32.png",
        "48":"icons/48.png",
        "128":"icons/128.png"
    },
    "permissions": [ "downloads", "activeTab"],
    "background":{}
}
```

popup.html as below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>PDF</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="popup.css" />
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>MIS</h1>
    <!-- <button id="grabBtn">Upload to Server</button> -->
</body>

</html>
```

And finally popup.js as below

```
var folder = "PDF_downloads";

chrome.downloads.onDeterminingFilename.addListener(
    function (item, suggest) {

        if (isPDF(item)) suggest({ filename: folder + "/" + item.filename });
        else suggest();
    }
);

function isPDF(item) {
    if (item.mime === "application/pdf") return true;
    else if (item.filename.match(/\.pdf$/i)) return true;
    else return false;
}

// const grabBtn = document.getElementById("grabBtn");
// grabBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
//     alert("CLICKED");
// })
```

Comment: Remove action and popup.html, rename popup.js to background.js and add `"service_worker": "background.js"` inside `background` section of your manifest.json. Note that the service worker script doesn't have a document.

Comment: _"Am stuck"_ is not really a great description of the problem(s) you're facing.

Comment: yeah thanks. That comment has worked. what about sending the file to a remote server and maitaining a copy in downloads folder. Its a bit tricky but any help will be appreciated. @wOxxOm

Comment: I have changed background.js to this but still not hitting external server. Not working.
``https://jsfiddle.net/Petach/0tp6unyx/3/``